# PyCharm: Cannot import python library

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a project with 2 Python scripts, both of them are Tensorflow models.

I opened a new script called paper.py and imported pandas and numpy.

However, when I typed

```
import seaborn as sns
```

one of the Tensorflow models immediately starts training.

The same happens with

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

What is the problem?

EDIT: 
I checked the project interpreter and I do have both packages listed in the environment I'm using.
I also found out that running

```
import statsmodels as sm
```

is fine, but running

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

starts training the other script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the python interpreter in File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter and be sure you use a correct one that includes all the stuff you need.